# adding elements into a vector using MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, vector, matlab-guide

I am new to matlab and I'm trying to make a progrem which gets parameters from the user(using gui)for x value and y value,puts them into 2 different vectors and when the user is done it uses plot to make a graph out of the two vectors.

here is what I tries to do:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
x=[];
y=[];
a=str2double(get(handles.edit1,'string'));
b=str2double(get(handles.edit2,'string'));
handles.x=[x a];
handles.y=[y b];
guidata(hObject, handles);




function Doit_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
axes(handles.axes1)
handles.x;
handles.y;
handles.m=handles.x;
handles.n=handles.y;
plot(handles.m,handles.n);
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

but the plot function won't work.I'm tring to get a and b from the edit text in the gui and put them into vector x and vector y,and when I'm done  adding all the element I want I'm trying to use the full vectors in the Doit function.
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following code:

```
x=[];
y=[];
% ...
handles.x=[x a];
handles.y=[y b];
```

every time the user is done inserting values, all he gets are two points (`a` and `b`)... because:

```
handles.x = [x a]; % x=[]
handles.x = [[] a];
handles.x = a;
```

You should implement a button for clearing your `handles.x` and `handles.y` variables when the user wants to restart from scratch, and change your callback code so that values are appended to the existing ones, as follows:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    handles.x = [handles.x str2double(get(handles.edit1,'string'))];
    handles.y = [handles.y str2double(get(handles.edit2,'string'))];
    guidata(hObject,handles);
```

Then (`handles.axes1` is supposed to be an existing axis within your GUI so you are right about clearing it, but I would use `cla` instead):

```
function Doit_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    cla(handles.axes1);
    plot(handles.axes1,handles.x,handles.y);
    guidata(hObject,handles);
```